# How to create a shortcut to build and run Rust code from inside VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

consider this simple rust program:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, Man!");
}
```

I created a shortcut in Vs Code at:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+enter",
  "command": "rust-analyzer.run"
}
```

Now when i press `ctrl+shift+enter`, it should build and run the rust program and display the output in the built in terminal in VS Code.

When i press `ctrl+shift+enter`, it opens a window for me at the top offering several options, i choose `run <program_name>`:

[image]

Now i want VS Code to choose `run <program_name>` automatically, i do not want it to offer the 3 options, i want it to just build and run when i press `ctrl+shift+enter`.

Any ideas how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the shortcut to `cargo run` instead?

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+enter",
  "command": "cargo run"
}
```

Comment: set it where ?!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I do not find a way to add a new shortcut or change the command in an existing one. Have you tried testing that before adding it as a possible answer ?

If you tried doing that in the JSON file of the keybindings, you will get "command 'cargo run' not found"

Comment: I didn't. I probably shouldn't have commented without trying it out first, but now that I have, I don't a way to get around the options prompt. You can just use the arrow keys and hit enter to get the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

just press Enter button one more time after hitting your key binding, because first option is always `run`.
By the way, thankyou for sharing. I was also finding some way to run Rust programs.

Answer (score 0):

I created this shortcut in my `keybindings.json`. It just runs a command in terminal. `\u000D` is that symbol that you pass to your terminal by pressing `enter` after typing a command:

```json
  {
    "key": "alt+c r",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
      "text": "cargo run\u000D"
    },
    "when": "editorLangId == 'rust'"
  },
```

You can also make similar shortcuts for `cargo new`, `cargo build` or whatever else you want. I like to bind my terminal command shortcuts to `alt+X` where `X` is the first letter of the utility name (like `alt+c` for `cargo`), and the second button specifies what exactly my command should do (`alt+c r` for `cargo run`). It is just a personal preference though.